# PHP escapeshellcmd() breaks ImageMagick convert command using '>' character

Tags: php, escaping, imagemagick, exec, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick 6.6.9 on an Ubuntu 12 server. The problem I have is that my ImageMagick convert command, which I run through PHP using the `shell_exec` function (but have also tried `exec`), has characters in it which the PHP `escapeshellcmd` function escapes with a `\`

Here is my PHP code:

```
$result = exec(escapeshellcmd($convertString));
```

Here is my sample convert command:

`/usr/bin/convert "/Users/rich/Sites/example/1234.JPG" -quality 85 -auto-orient -thumbnail "640x88>" "/Users/rich/Sites/example/1234-thumb.jpg"`

And finally here is the convert command after it has been run through `escapeshellcmd`:

`/usr/bin/convert "/Users/rich/Sites/example/1234.JPG" -quality 85 -auto-orient -thumbnail "640x88\>" "/Users/rich/Sites/example/1234-thumb.jpg"`

The problem is that the escaped `\>` character results in an ImageMagick error:

> convert: invalid argument for option -thumbnail': 640x88> @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2770.

Does anyone know of a way that I can get around this? I have trawled the ImageMagick documentation and while they acknowledge the problem they don't seem to provide any other way of resizing an image without using the special unix characters:

> The Only Shrink Flag ('>' flag) is a special character in both UNIX Shell and in Window batch scripts, and you will need to escape that character (using backslash '>' in shell, and '^>' in windows batch). It is also special in and HTML web pages, so PHP scripts also may need some special handling.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had extra `"` (quote marks) around the `-thumbnail "640x88\>"` size options. For reference, the correct, escaped convert command should have been:

`/usr/bin/convert "/Users/rich/Sites/example/1234.JPG" -quality 85 -auto-orient -thumbnail 640x88\> "/Users/rich/Sites/example/1234-thumb.jpg"`

Comment: Thanks ! although, this works for UX-based environments, for Windows it should either be `-thumbnail "640x88>"` or `-thumbnail 640x88^>`